# Custom paging on lists through XSLT

Tags: list, xslt, paging

I am working with vwstyles.xsl to implement custom paging on lists. The requirement I have is to have first and last button on the paging panel but can't work out how to direct the user to the last page as there is no total row count being passed through to the XSLT.

Is this possible with XSLT?

Can I use extension methods so I can hook up C# to the XSL?

Is there any other way of me implementing the required functionality?

Comment: Kindly share the code once you get it works ya.. looking for end button to go to the last page but can't find any reference. I tried to find the total items or rows when using pagination but it limit the query based on the rowlimit. Need to find a way to get the real total rows list when using pagination.

Comment: That is exactly the same issue I am having, doubting whether it is actually possible without a nasty hack

Comment: @ixiel: I went ahead and converted your answer to a comment. With a bit more reputation, you will be able to [post comments](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2):

When you're trying to find the last page can't you count the amount of rows that you have?

```
<xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

But you can use xsl to do paging.
You can easily use jquery for this google .."Jquery Paging"
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can get the paging mostly working, the bit I can't get working is the last button that takes you to the last page as the XSL doesn't have a total list row count. Dlo you know if that is possible?

Comment: Post some snippet code
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XSLT count() function to count the number of child elements. That should let you generate the number of pages to have.